# multiple target for ajaxSubmit in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '#picture_preview',
            success:  afterSuccess //call function after success
});
```

I use the above code to upload an image into server and the uploaded image is pushed into the target specified. It all work fine.

But i also need the same image to be displayed in another div element.

Comment: lets try this: `target: $('#picture_preview, #another_target')`